# Preimage by birational maps

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, characteristic-classes, resolution-of-singularities

I am looking for an example (I guess that in complex projective space $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ is good) such that satisfy the following condition (in non trivial case, for this assume $X \neq \tilde{X}$):

Let $i: X \longrightarrow M$ be an embedding of a closed subvariety $X$ in a nonsingular variety (algebraic) $M$ and let $\pi :\tilde{M} \longrightarrow M$ be a proper birational map with $\tilde{M}$ a nonsingular variety, such that $\pi^{-1}(X)= \tilde{X}$ (total transform) is a hypersurface with its singular scheme, denoted by $\tilde{Y}$ has the condition $codim_{\tilde{M}}(\tilde{Y})\geq 3$ and $\pi|_{\tilde{M}\setminus \tilde{X}}$ is an isomorphism.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why can't you take $\tilde{M} = M$ and $\tilde{X} = X$ a hypersurface with the properties you like?

Comment: Thank you Sasha. This is possible, but rather trivial. I need to edit the post, because I look for a non trivial example. Moreover, I need of a class of birational maps that satify above conditions. I know I will go to other hand of embedded resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are no such non trivial examples. Indeed, since $M$ is smooth and $\pi$ non trivial, the exceptional locus, say $E$, of $\pi$ in $\tilde{M}$ has codimension $1$. Now, as $\tilde{X}$ is assumed to be an hypersurface, it implies that the strict transform of $X$, say $\pi^{-1}(X)$ is a hypersurface in $\tilde{M}$.

The ambient variety $\tilde{M}$ being smooth, the intersection of $\pi^{-1}(X)$ and $E$, if non-empty, must have codimension $1$ in $\pi^{-1}(X)$. The hypothesis *$\pi_{\tilde{M}\backslash \tilde{X}}$ is an isomorphism* guarantees that the image of $E$ is included in $X$, which implies that the intersection of $\pi^{-1}(X)$ and $E$ is non empty. Hence $E$ and $\pi^{-1}(X)$ are unions of irreducible components of $\tilde{X}$ and they meet in codimension $1$ in $\pi^{-1}(X)$, so that the singular locus of $\tilde{X}$ has codimension $1$ in $\pi^{-1}(X)$. And thus codimension $2$ in $\tilde{M}$ because $\tilde{X}$ is a hypersurface in $\tilde{M}$.

Comment: Thank you Libli for your answer. I think that you are sure if we consider the blow up or a  big resolution (that replaced, for instance, the singular set by a hypersurface). On the other hand, there is the notion of "small resolution" (https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Small-resolutions-of-the-Segre-cubic-Finkelnberg/e0ebdf1320ccc48a3a04a5baadab6726c2bd1a8c) that repaced the singular set by, in some seting, curves or a "small set".

I guess that maybe there exist a birational map (not a blow up) satisfying the non trivial above condition.

Comment: The exceptional locus of a birational morphism between smooth varieties is always a divisor.